# Ext-Tidy on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to get the PHP Tidy extension to run on my Heroku instance that I've set up.  I've added ext-tidy to my composer.json file and run composer update to update the composer.lock file.

However when I push the changes to Heroku, the build fails as the Heroku buildpack doesn't include the Tidy extension.

Is there a way to get Composer to bundle the Tidy extension so that it gets pushed to Heroku (I'm using a Windows machine so I don't know if this will complicate matters if it is possible)?  Or do I need to create a new buildpack with Tidy integrated?  If so, I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction to be able to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: No, unfortunately not